# HOw to reload the present UI details once is switch from different UI in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have two forms one is trainee_view.ui
and other is enter_new_trainee.ui

so for that i have trainee_view.cpp,trainee_view.h  to see the list of Trainee in DB
and enter_new_trainee.cpp,enter_new_trainee.h  to enter new trainee details

now in trainee_view.ui i have a push button "ADD Trainee"
so if i click this button it will go to "enter_new_trainee.ui"

```
   void trainee_view::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
   {
     newtrainee=new enter_new_trainee(this);
     newtrainee->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
     newtrainee->show();

   // connect(newtrainee, SIGNAL(destroyed()), this, SLOT(refresh_form()));
   }
```

so by using     connect()      i am trying to refresh the trainee_view after entering the new trainee details. so how can i emmit the signal from 
2nd form to 1st form such that i call     refresh_form()     method in 1st form .
I tried to use      destroyed()    signal on newtrainee but could not refresh my trainee_view form.

To be MOre simple . i just want to get an object is destroyed or not so if destroyed i can call     refresh()     method to load back the changes done on widget
for that i opted      connect()     method so how should i call that. becoz if i call 
      connect(newtrainee, SIGNAL(destroyed()), this, SLOT(refresh_form()));
there is no effect i.e nothing is loading into the view.

am newbie to qt so pls try to help me.
Thank YOu.

Comment: A [mcve] is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand your app, but I think you misunderstand the concept of Signals and Slots. [Look here for some examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). In some simplification you can look at signal and slots this way: `connect()` command is a place which will not do anything - it just stay and keep listening for a signal. So you should place it in `trainee_view.cpp`. That's the first part and I see you did it correct, or almost correct. But you need also something that will send the signal, and this is exactly what `emit()` command do - it should be placed in `enter_new_trainee.cpp` just after description of generation new entry. For example, let assume user input new entry in LineEdit in UI:

```
[...]
QString newEntry = ui->LineEdit->text(); //Save entry to variable
emit(newEntry); //Emit it to signal slot
[...]
```

Comment: One problem is solved i.e if i click on " close"  push button am emitting a signal stop() and in main form am assigning a slot for that signal . Now the problem is if we click on " X " close button on right top of the widget , the problem stays on . how can i handle that. ? i tried to emit the same signal in  overriddden  closeEvents() method